# Makefile for kernel module

Tags: linux-kernel, makefile

Hi I am trying to write a 'Hello World' kernel module.
I wrote the following C code: 
Module514.c

```
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/init.h>


MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("BMC")
MODULE_DESCRIPTION(" My module]")


static int __init module514(void){
    printk(KERN_INFO"Hello World");
    return 0;
    }

static void __exit module514_cleanup(void){
    printk(KERN_INFO"unloaded")
    } 


  module_init(module514);
  module_exit(module514_cleanup);
```

Then created the following Makefile

```
obj-m += Module514.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

But when I give make I get the following message.

```
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

What am I doing wrong.

Comment: Can you post output "make -n"?. Also you code will not compile, semi-colon ;  is missing

Comment: @Sasi Response for 'make -n' is the same "make: Nothing to be done for `all'.". Thanks corrected the code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here seems to have been caused by my Vim configuration. When I used TAB to indent the makefile spaces were getting inserted instead of TAB. Once I corrected this using a different editor all is going file.

PS: Also makefile need to be named with capital M = Makefile

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24709389/error-in-generating-ko-file-for-simple-hello-world-module-for-linux-kernel/31968848#31968848

it's good to start with reading the kernel build process as given above