# error in generating .ko file for simple hello world module for linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, makefile

I am a beginner in linux kernel development and trying to load a simple module in linux.
I have created an hello.c file, to be loaded as kernel module.

> ```
> #include <linux/module.h>  
> #include <linux/kernel.h>  
> #include <linux/init.h>    
>
> MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
> MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A Simple Hello World module");
>
> static int __init hello_init(void)
> {
>     printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world!\n");
>     return 0;   
> }
>
> static void __exit hello_cleanup(void)
> {
>     printk(KERN_INFO "Cleaning up module.\n");
> }
>
> module_init(hello_init);
> module_exit(hello_cleanup);
> ```

this hello.c and the makefile both, I have kept in /home/linux/ directory.

makefile

> ```
> obj-m +=hello.o
>
> src= /usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic
> all:
>   $(MAKE) -C $(src) SUBDIR-$(PWD) modules
> clean:
>   rm -rf *.o *.ko
> ```

to generate .ko file, when I run the make command on terminal from the /home/linux directory , I get following error

> ```
> h2o@h2o-Vostro-1015:~/linux$ make
> make -C /usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic SUBDIR-/home/h2o/linux modules
> make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic'
> make[1]: *** No rule to make target `SUBDIR-/home/h2o/linux'.  Stop.
> make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic'
> make: *** [all] Error 2
> ```

kindly advise what am I missing or doing wrong..

Comment: What text are you refering to? It is not `SUBDIR-$(PWD)`, but `SUBDIRS=$(PWD)`... And the SUBDIRS syntax is a old one, by now it would rather be `M=$(PWD)`. Have you tried to understand what you are doing?

Comment: thanks ysomane, I modified the makefile and one more mistake I was doing was that I was referring to /usr/src but now I have learnt that its not guaranteed that headers file will always be located in this directory, but it will surely be located in /lib/modules directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Makefile

  > obj-m := hello.o  # Module Name is hello.c
  >
  > KDIR  := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
  >
  > all:  $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
  >
  > clean:    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean   $(RM) Module.markers
  >   modules.order

its not guaranteed that headers file will always be located in /usr/src directory, but it will surely be located in /lib/modules directory.

- make sure  that system has latest header files

to find out which header files to be present
run `

> uname -r

on terminal, output will be like

> `3.5.0-17-generic`

to install header files run

> `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
$(MAKE) -C $(src) SUBDIR-$(PWD) modules
```

But it seems like you want:

```
$(MAKE) -C $(src)/SUBDIR-$(PWD) modules
```

Or something along those lines; where does the source code live?  You need to `-C` there.

Comment: Thanks Carl.. but as per the text, the commands in make file are correct, and I tried yours too but it didnt work. the source code and makefile both exist in same directory i.e /home/linux
do you think I need to change the location..?

Answer (score 0):

Kernel build system is a bit complex.  It would be good to read the [**kernel build process**](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt) documentation. Which gives better understanding about, say,

- Targets like   ---  `modules / modules_install`
- Options like   ---  `-C $KDIR / M=$PWD`
- Command Syntax ---
- `$ make -C <path_to_kernel_src> M=$PWD`

  `$ make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=$PWD`

  `$ make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=$PWD modules_install`
- Loadable module goals --- `obj-m`

etc...